# How to upgrade Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 to Update 2?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 has been released, however it doesn't detail any methods of upgrading from Update 1 to Update 2 - and no updates are shown for it in the 'Extensions and Updates' dialog.

Does anybody know the correct method of upgrading from Update 1 to Update 2?

Comment: Click on the [download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129) then run the EXE file, doesn't get more basic than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that they forgot to put it inside the updates, you can download it from their web
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Comment: Will doing this overwrite anything set-up on my Update 1 installation? Or will everything be set-up pretty similar?

Comment: There are no guarantees, but unless they have changed, removed, augmented existing systems (for which you have configuration), nothing should change in that regard.

Comment: the settings should remain the same, maybe if they added a new feature to something that you have specifically changed it you have some problem, but from my experience, I,ve never had problems with that. But I've had problems of funny results having libraries created in different versions. Good practice to recreate all if possible.

Answer (score 45):

A little late, but it appears you can upgrade through VS now. This seemed to work for me: under **Tools** > **Extensions & Updates...**

A window will pop up and on the left hand panel click on **Updates**.

You should be able to find the update there; mine had the label **Visual Studio 2015 Update 2**

[image]

Comment: Also note at this time even though the Extensions and Updates window will show `Visual Studio 2015 Update 2` (if you are on Update 1), it will actually download a small exe for Update 3 and running the exe will update you to `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3`

Comment: So I got the exe for Update 3, but the "Update Now" button doesn't get enabled for it. Its greyed out, and stays the same. Any leads appreciated.